# Spark: triggering alerts when executors fail

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, monitoring, spark-streaming

We've been running into a bug that causes our executors to continuously fail. On the surface, the application still appears healthy, and it has taken upwards of 3 days for the application to crash after such incidents. We want to add monitoring that can be used to alert us in this situation.

I've decided to monitor batch completed events: if the executors are continuously failing, no batches should complete. This had the added benefit of tracking when batches are backed up. I achieved this by registering a SparkStreamingListener that marks a meter every time onBatchCompleted is called. While testing it's efficacy, I killed the application, while keeping the driver running. Much to my surprise, batches are still reported as completing.

Is this expected behaviour, or a bug? If this is expected behaviour, does anyone have any alternative methods for tracking when executors are continuously failing / the overall health of the spark application?

Comment: How did you kill the application while the driver was running? The driver is the one managing the applications lifetime. Also, perhaps share what the *bug* is, maybe we can further assist in solving it.

Comment: We haven't been able to pin-point the bug, adding monitoring to notify us when it begins is one step towards finding its root cause. I've killed the application, not the driver, using the spark UI.

Comment: That *should* kill the driver, since the application is managed by the driver, that's the only way to kill an app. But, it doesn't always work from my experience.